# Missing IBOutlets in GADUnifiedNativeAdView in xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, native, iboutlet

I've been trying to implement native Google adMob ads in my iOS app. This is the tutorial I'm following:

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/advanced

I successfully installed the pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'. The tutorial then says to give a UIView  (in storyboard or xib file)the class GADUnifiedNativeAdView, and then to add subviews and link them to the IBOutlets provided by GADUnifiedNativeAdView. However, I am not able to see the IBOutlets.

[Added class GADUnifiedNativeAdView to UIView in Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9l4W.png)

[Missing IBOutlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ise.png)

Comment: I am getting the same problem, did you find any solution ?

Comment: As per Mobile Ads SDK Team, It's a know issue.
Link: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/YKCW9Be2_cs/m/juXZ-eKKAwAJ

Comment: Any solution, i have same problem

Comment: Is this still an issue in 2022?

Comment: you find any solution?